# Regex for digits in end of string Python

Tags: python, regex, string

I want to get boolean for all strings having digits at the end of string. For example

```
import re
# list of strings
li = ['/Usein-kysytyt-kysymykset;jsessionid=0727CD5A45A05D3CBD5A26D459C34D9D.xxlapp11',
      '/vaatteet/naisten-vaatteet/naisten-takit/c/120204',
      '/pyoraily/pyorailyvarusteet/pyorankuljetuslaukut-ja-vannepussit/c/100818_8']
for i in li:
    if(bool(re.match('\d+$', i))):
        print(i)
```

So this should work and return me `True` for `li[1]` and `li[2]` and `False` for `li[0]` but it is returning false for all elements in the list. What is wrong here ?

Comment: `re.match` only matches at the beginning of a string. Use `re.search` instead!

Comment: `re.match` should do the trick, but in `li` I see that all strings end with digits so it should return all of them.

Comment: Wouldnt you expect `li[0]` to be True also since it ends with `11`?

Comment: Yes it'll be True as well. I thought it was alphabet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `re.findall()`

```
for i in li:
    if(bool(re.findall('\d+$', i))):
        print(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

*Try this:*

```
for i in li:
#get last occurrence of that string
    l = i[len(i) - 1]
    #if it is a number then do following
    if l.isdigit():
        print(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

The python docs about `re.match`:

> If zero or more characters at the beginning of string match the regular expression pattern, return a corresponding MatchObject instance.

To find out if the last element of a string is a digit, use this instead:

```
for i in li:
    if(bool(re.search(r'\d+$', i))):
        print(i)
```